# Can't access polymorphic associated model's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a few models that use a Photo polymorphic model. It's all good and fine for saving or accessing the photos' attributes via console or inspect or logger, but if I try to call them directly in the view with, for example, `@banner.photo.file`, it returns a `undefined method 'file' etc for nil:Nil`

Photos are being uploaded via paperclip and all models are set with `has_one :photo, :as => :imageable` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :allow_destroy => true`. And the Photo model is set as `belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true` and `has_attached_file :file`.

These are the columns for the Photo model:

```
id:integer
file:string
imageable_id:integer
imageable_type:string
file_file_name:string
file_content_type:string
file_file_size:integer
```

(besides created_at etc)

In my view:

```
<% @banners.each do |b| %> 
  <%= b.inspect %><br /> 
  <%= b.photo.inspect %><br /><br /> 
<% end %>
```

You can see the inspect at http://bdyvu2.hospedagemweb.net/

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does `Photo.find(3)` return an object or `nil`?

Comment: Photo.find(1/2) does return either of the two existing photos

Comment: Please give me the returned value of `Photo.find(3)` without any valueation

Comment: Says Couldn't find Photo with id=3 :)